# table cell background color change with checkbox

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$('#selectall1').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.first').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
    $('.second').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
    $('.third').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  } else {
    $('.first').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('#selectall2').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.second').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
    $('.first').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
    $('.third').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  } else {
    $('.second').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$('#selectall3').click(function(event) {
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.third').each(function() {
      this.checked = true;
    });
    $('.first').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
    $('.second').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  } else {
    $('.third').each(function() {
      this.checked = false;
    });
  }
});

$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  var th = $(this),
    name = th.prop('name');
  if (th.is(':checked')) {
    $(':checkbox[name="' + name + '"]').not($(this)).prop('checked', false);
  }
});

$("input:checkbox[class='first']").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight1");
});

$("input:checkbox[class='second']").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight2");
});

$("input:checkbox[class='third']").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass("highlight3");
});
```

```css
div.highlight1 {
    background-color: #9FF781;
}
div.highlight2 {
    background-color: #F78181;
}
div.highlight3 {
    background-color: #8181F7;
}
div.highlight {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>
      <INPUT type="checkbox" id="selectall1" />
    </th>
    <th>
      <INPUT type="checkbox" id="selectall2" />
    </th>
    <th>
      <INPUT type="checkbox" id="selectall3" />
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="first" name="1" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="second" name="1" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="third" name="1" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="first" name="2" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="second" name="2" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="third" name="2" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="first" name="3" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="second" name="3" />
      </div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" class="third" name="3" />
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to change td background color when corresponding check box is checked. User must select **only one check box** among three. User must be able to select **all check boxes** at once when he wants and **corresponding check boxes td background colors** **should change**. I've some stuff but not completely done. I'm struct at some place and some redundancy is there.

[Demo fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2b4f0rs9/)

[image]

Comment: why not use radio buttons instead of checkboxes if they are only allowed to select one in a row?

Comment: off course we can use not only check boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How's this:

```js
var selectall = $('.selectall');
selectall.click(function (event) {
    $('.' + $(this).data('class')).each(function () {
        this.checked = true;
        highlight(this, $(this).closest('td'));
    });
});

$('input[type=radio]').not(selectall).on('click', function() {
    highlight(this, $(this).closest('td'));
});

function highlight(radio, radioCell) {
    if (radio.checked) {
        radioCell.closest('tr').children('td.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        radioCell.addClass('highlight');
    }
}
```

```css
td:nth-child(3n + 1).highlight {
    background-color: #9FF781;
}
td:nth-child(3n + 2).highlight {
    background-color: #F78181;
}
td:nth-child(3n + 3).highlight {
    background-color: #8181F7;
}
div.highlight {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <INPUT type="radio" name="selectall" id="selectall1" class="selectall" data-class="first" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <INPUT name="selectall" type="radio" id="selectall2" class="selectall" data-class="second" />
        </th>
        <th>
            <INPUT name="selectall" type="radio" id="selectall3" class="selectall" data-class="third" />
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="first" name="1" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="second" name="1" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="third" name="1" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="first" name="2" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="second" name="2" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="third" name="2" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="first" name="3" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="second" name="3" />
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" class="third" name="3" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: without div is it possible to change corresponding td background color. means applying background color directly to td. Bcoz i've some div alignment problem. With the above code only half of td cell color is changed in the middle.

Comment: @Satya, see edit to above post (change in js and styles).  If you remove the div, then just change `closest('td')` back to `parent()`